# Login form showing the first time with successful login

Tags: php, sql

They keywords was a bit meaningless to search and I couldn't find anything. Hope you guys help me.
Here's the code :

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']))
    {
        include ("loginSection.php");
    }
    else
    {
        include ("loggedON.php");
    }
?>
```

It is in my header. It works well but the problem is when username and password is correct it shows the form the first time along with the "Login Successful" Message. but after navigating it will be fine. is there anyway to check userid in session before the page loads so it doesn't show the login form that first time?

```
 <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['userpassSubmit']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";
        $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);

        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result();

        if ($statement->num_rows == 1)
        {
            $statement->bind_result($_SESSION['userid'], $_SESSION['username']);
            $statement->fetch();
            echo "login successful";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "incorrect username password combination";
        }
    }        



    echo '
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">

                <form id="regForm" role="form" action='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].' method="post" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username"><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"><br>
                    </div>
                    <input name="userpassSubmit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="login">
                </form>

              </div>
         </div>';
?>
```

Comment: This appears fine - the error must be elsewhere in your code. Where do you put `session_start();`?

Comment: Add code section of Login section page, for clearer understanding..

Comment: I added the code for that. maybe I have to explain it better, the code is working correctly right now. the only problem is the first time with successful login I still see the form. but it goes away when I change the page as if it checks the session right after that.

Comment: where is the second php code stored (the form and the code to check user and password)? In what page? loginsection.php?

Comment: Yes it is in the loginSection.php. loginSection is in header.php (gets included there) and i returns the POST parameters to PHP_SELF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create logout page or clear cookies to show your login page.
In logout page you need to destroy or unset the session.

```
**logout.php**

session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['userid']))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['userid']); 
    }
```

Comment: no Actually the problem is not that. I has to work like this : If you have logged in successfully don't show the form. if not show the login form.
it works right now, but the first time with successful login I still see my login form. but after that when I navigate to another page it doesn't show itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that

I think below code is add to your loginSection.php page

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION['userid']))
  {

?>

  <script>

    window.location.href='loggedON.php';

  </script>

<?php

  }

    if (!empty($_POST['userpassSubmit']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";
        $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);

        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result();

        if ($statement->num_rows == 1)
        {
            $statement->bind_result($_SESSION['userid'], $_SESSION['username']);
            $statement->fetch();
            echo "login successful";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "incorrect username password combination";
        }
    }        



    echo '
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">

                <form id="regForm" role="form" action='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].' method="post" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username"><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"><br>
                    </div>
                    <input name="userpassSubmit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="login">
                </form>

              </div>
         </div>';
?>
```